# How to Open .win Files in windows 7?

Tags: database, windows

I am installing [Alenka](https://github.com/antonmks/Alenka) and need to run  Makefile.win file in windows 7.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Visual Studio, run the Visual Studio Command prompt from the Start menu, change to the directory containing Makefile.win and type this:

```
nmake -f Makefile.win
```

You can also use the normal command prompt and run vsvars32.bat (c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools for VS2008). This will set up the environment to run nmake and find the compiler tools.